# Apple Swift 3.0 Data

Tags: swift, file, swift3, nsdata

I'm trying to use:

```
init(contentsOf: URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions)
```

in Swift 3.0 with xCode 8.0. The exact statement I am using is:

```
let jsonData = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL(file_path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
```

I have also tried:

```
let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(file_path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
```

I am following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779617-init)

This does not compile, complaining about incorrect argument labels in call.

I'm a Swift newbie, so please be gentle. `file_path` is a string obtained from an `NSOpenPanel` and stringified using `stringValue`.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it's Swift convention to use `camelCase` rather than `snake_case`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use string paths in conjunction with `NSOpenPanel`, get the `url` property – that avoids the extra step to create the URL – and wrap the `Data` initializer in a `do - catch` block.

```
if let url = openPanel.url {
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
        // do things with jsonData
    } catch {
       print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding string paths might be good advice, but it needs some justification. It also doesn't seem to have much to do with the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: I added  some justification

Comment: What it complains of is: Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'contentsOf:options:_:' expected 'bytesNoCopy:count:deallocator:')

Comment: Try it with omitting the `options` parameter: `Data(contentsOf: url)`

Comment: No, that does a `Cannot convert value of type() -> () to expected argument type 'Data.ReadingOptions')` and adding an unlabeled argument to the end doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that you're talking about Swift **3**? The syntax in the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just missed the parameter label.  Also, no need for the init keyword in your Data constructor.

```
let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath), options: .mappedIfSafe)
```